# Auto populate form fields based on serial input or pull listings from other websites?

Tags: database, forms, sync

Please forgive me if I'm missing something obvious. I have created a website that allows dealers to sale their used equipment. Dealers are complaining that it takes too long to create a listing for each piece of equipment.

My boss has asked me if there is a way to link to a dealer's website and pull any new equipment that they upload and pull updates as well. We would be pulling from multiple dealers' websites. Should I even consider this possibility? Is there an efficient way to do this?

Another task that my boss has asked me to look into is the possibility of auto populating forms based on a serial input. Wouldn't I need a database full of serial number that are linked to make, model, etc.? I would love to hear any thoughts or suggestions.

Comment: does these third party web sites have the RSS feed?

Comment: you should consider asking questions one by one. looks like you have two separate.

Comment: I don't see an rss feed on the website. The website is [link](http://www.trax-plus.com/inv.htm?http://www.machinerytrader.com/listings/construction-equipment/for-sale/list/category/1035?ETID=1&pcid=3160685&dlr=1&Cond=used). Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: you need to search on "how to find RSS for the web site?" looks that the web site link you provided uses the info from another web site starting with "http://www.mac..."

Comment: Oh wow! I don't know how I missed that. So, they are pulling the listings from machinerytrader.com. How would I go about pulling content to my website? Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: i am sorry this is not the kind of web site you think at the moment.